# Sort 2d data by a calculated values

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli

The code below:

```
<?php
echo "<h3>Result</h3>";
$attribute1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT min(c1) as min1, max(c2) as max1, max(c3) as max2 from tb_alternative");
$atr1 = mysqli_fetch_array($attribute1);
    $sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from tb_alternative");
    while($r3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $point = ((($atr1['min1']/$r3['c1'])*$bobot[0])+
        (($r3['c2']/$atr1['max1'])*$bobot[1])+
        (($r3['c3']/$atr1['max2'])*$bobot[2]));

?>
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $r3['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r3['alternative']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $point?></td>
</tr>
<?php            
    }
?>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

How to sort data by total point?, the total points are calculated, not from the database

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php. Or do the calculations in the query and sort there.

Comment: I think you are looking for SQL sort instead.

Comment: It can not be done in MySQL because  `$bobot` is not part of SQL result

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Sure it can. Include `$bobot`'s values in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the result, but not when displaying the result within `mysqli_fetch` loop.

1. Fetch your query result to an array & calc your point there
2. Sort your array with [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
3. Display your data with their standalone loop (like `foreach`)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Both of them would work best if you kept your PHP and HTML separate. The first option uses [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) and the second uses PHP `usort()` function.

## Using window functions in SQL

You can use `MAX() OVER()` which will give you the maximum value of each column in each row. Assuming that the values in `$bobot` are not coming from the SQL query you would need to pass them to SQL to be used in the calculation. Then you can perform the whole calculation in a single SQL query and sort using `ORDER BY`

For example:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, alternative, 
        (min(c1) OVER()/c1) * ? + (c2/max(c2) OVER()) * ? + (c3/max(c3) OVER()) * ? AS point
    FROM tb_alternative
    ORDER BY point');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $bobot[0], $bobot[1], $bobot[2]);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

```
echo "<h3>Result</h3>";
echo "<table>";
foreach ($data as $r3) :
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $r3['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $r3['alternative'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $r3['point'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

## Using PHP `usort()`

If for some reason you can't use window functions or you prefer to have more complex calculations in PHP then you can do the same if you fetch all the values into an array and sort the array after the calculation.

```
$atr1 = $conn->query("SELECT min(c1) as min1, max(c2) as max1, max(c3) as max2 from tb_alternative")->fetch_assoc();
$sql3 = $conn->query("SELECT * from tb_alternative");
$data = [];
foreach ($sql3 as $row) {
    $data[] = [
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'alternative' => $row['alternative'],
        'point' => ($atr1['min1'] / $row['c1'] * $bobot[0]) + ($row['c2'] / $atr1['max1'] * $bobot[1]) + ($row['c3'] / $atr1['max2'] * $bobot[2])
    ];
}

usort($data, fn ($a, $b) => $b <=> $a);
// or if you are still using PHP 7.3:
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b <=> $a;
});
```

```
echo "<h3>Result</h3>";
echo "<table>";
foreach ($data as $r3) :
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $r3['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $r3['alternative'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $r3['point'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```